# Select all elements with class and without attribute using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup4, I can select all desired elements using the following:

`elements = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'some-class'})`

How can I restrict `elements` to only include anchor links with class `some-class` but without attributes such as `href="#"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `href` with `None`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <div>
...     <a class="some-class" href="#">11</a>
...     <a class="some-class">22</a>
...     <a class="some-class">33</a>
...     <a class="some-class" href="#">44</a>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'some-class'})
[<a class="some-class" href="#">11</a>, <a class="some-class">22</a>,
 <a class="some-class">33</a>, <a class="some-class" href="#">44</a>]
>>> soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'some-class', 'href': None})  # <--
[<a class="some-class">22</a>, <a class="some-class">33</a>]
```